# Completeness of $ L^{p} $ spaces and "rapidly Cauchy" sequences

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/books/royden-fitzpatrick/royden-fitzpatrick.pdf

In the book of Royden, the completeness of $ L^{p}    $ spaces has been done using what he calls "rapidly Cauchy" sequences.

A sequence $ f_{n} \in  X $, where $ X $ is a normed linear is said to be rapidly Cauchy if there is a sequence of positive reals $ \epsilon_{k} $ such that $ \sum_{  k  = 1 } ^ { \infty}  \epsilon_{k}         $ is convergent and

$$    ||        f_{k+1} - f_{k} ||    < \epsilon_{k}   ^{2}         ,       $$

for all $ k \in \mathbb{N}                                      $.

However, I don't understand why do we need to square the $ \epsilon_{k} $. The proofs all work fine even if I just put $    \epsilon_{k} $ as an upper bound on the $ ||  f_{k+1} - f_{k} || $ norm.  As far as I see, all propositions and theorems up to the Reisz-Fischer Theorem remain valid.

**Question.**    What purpose does squaring the $ \epsilon_{k} $ term serve in the chapter?

Comment: May this be just a trick to make computations easier? It seems as the whole "rapidly Cauchy" thing is a trick to simplify the work, as actually you want to show that every Cauchy sequence converge, and the idea seems: "ok, let's just show that every rapidly Cauchy sequence converge, as all Cauchy seq. have a rapidly Cauchy subseq."

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, notice that the condition is not actually the same if you remove the square. If you remove the square then there are many more acceptable sequences of functions, for example $\| f_{k+1}-f_k \| \leq k^{-p}$ for $p \in (1,2]$ become acceptable.

Second of all, you can see how it is used in the proof of (in my edition) Theorem 6. Specifically the calculation in question is on page 147. They use Chebyshev's inequality to go from the rapidly Cauchy bound to a bound on the measure of a "bad" set. The way the calculation goes, you you wind up needing $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\| f_{k+1}-f_k \|_p^p}{\epsilon_k^p}<\infty$. So the numerator will need to be quite a bit smaller than $\epsilon_k^p$, and (since $p \in [1,\infty)$) it is sufficient for it to be smaller than $\epsilon_k^{2p}$.